# Can weblogic 12c listen to JMS queue in another domain in a different IP

Tags: java, jms, weblogic, weblogic-10.x, weblogic12c

I have a JMS queue configured in weblogic domain (lets call it "A").

Client is sending messages only to this queue in this weblogic domain. Now I want to listen to that queue from different weblogic doamin (lets call it "B") which is in different machine.

Please note that I need both of the domains (A & B) to listen to same queue in A.

So is there a way that B can listen to A's queue?

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a way to do this.
You need to set up a foreign JMS Provider in Domain B which connects to the queue in domain A.

Comment: Do I need to do any modifications to the application code to go with foreign JMS Proivider? or is it just the configurations at Weblogic?

Comment: It should be just configuration

Comment: I have referred several sites but still could not find a proper article which shows the step by step configuration, Could you please help me on this, may be you may have a proper guide to configure this.